# oracle 1=1 in join clause

Tags: oracle10g

What does it mean to say;

```
select col1,col2 from table1 join table2 on 1=1 where table2.status = '1'
```

Comment: Means the original dev likes writing obscure queries.

Comment: Check here : [In Oracle, is starting the SQL Query's WHERE clause with 1=1 useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069373/in-oracle-is-starting-the-sql-querys-where-clause-with-1-1-useful)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a cross join to me.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I see predicates like "1=1" in queries generated by a tool.

The pseudocode for the tool would be something like:

```
sql := sql || '1=1';
FOR i IN 1 .. predicates.COUNT LOOP
  sql := sql || ' AND ' || predicates(i);
END LOOP
```

This way, it doesn't have to worry about omitting the "AND" for the first predicate.