# Does adding 1=1 to a WHERE clause a drop in performance?

Tags: teradata

Consider the following SQL:

```
select * from dbname.tablename
where
    field1 = 'a' and
    field2 = 'b' and
    field3 = 'c' and
    1=1
```

You may wonder why I would add `1=1` at the end of the WHERE clause.  For ad-hoc querying, I do this so that I can comment out any combination of conditions without having to modify the SQL.  Using this SQL, I can comment out `field1 = 'a' and` and the SQL will work because of the trailing `1=1` condition.  Consider this SQL without this little trick:

```
    field1 = 'a' and
    field2 = 'b' and
    field3 = 'c'
```

Commenting out `field3 = 'c'` will break the SQL because it will look at `field2 = 'b' and` as the final condition and it will bark at you with, "and WHAT??"

The reason why I am asking this is because I have been known to forget to remove the `1=1` from the WHERE clause before I paste the SQL into a production query.  I am wondering if this impedes performance.  `1=1` is a constant condition, so is there really a strenuous calculation being made here even if the recordset contains 10,000 rows?

Comment: @oscilatibgcretin Here is another **[Link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7983/does-where-1-1-usually-have-an-impact-on-query-performance)** To support my **answer**. **:)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL 1=1 Performance Hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049512/t-sql-1-1-performance-hit)

Comment: I tried deleting, but there's an answer, so I just marked it.  I was surprised to see others have come up with the exact same trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sweet and simple words **NO**.

Please refer the **[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049512/t-sql-1-1-performance-hit/1049519#1049519)**