# Does SQL Server optimise constant expressions?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, query-optimization

If I do something like this in SQL Server...

```
select *
from mytable
where 1=1
```

...does the `1=1` condition get optimised out, or is it actually evaluated for each row?

I'd also be interested in knowing how other DBMSes behave in this regard, particularly MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL 1=1 Performance Hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049512/t-sql-1-1-performance-hit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL Server:**

**First example:**

`1=1` predicate is automatically removed by SQL Server Query Optimizer because it's always `true`:
[image]

**Second example:**

Because `1=2` predicate is always `false`, the execution plan don't includes a data access operator (`Table` / `Index` `Scan` / `Seek`) to read data from `dbo.Customer` table. Instead, the execution plan includes an `Constant Scan` operator which will return the list of columns from `dbo.Customer` table without any row. This is [contradiction detection](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/tag/contradiction-detection/)  in action :-)

[image]

Note: I used SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Test it with `EXPLAIN PLAN` for MySQL and `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` for SQL Server