# Filter table depending on variable and use index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm filtering a table depending on if a variable is set or not. But the clustered index is not used. Is it possible to get the query to somehow use the index. (I cant dynamically create the query in this case)

```
DECLARE @UseFilter as bit = 1

select pkEventId from EventEvent
where pkEventID = 57637 or @UseFilter = 0
```

Execution plan (not using index)
[image]
If I skip the `Or` the index is used.

```
select pkEventId from EventEvent
where pkEventID = 57637
```

Execution plan (Using index)
[image]

Comment: you do an `IF @UseFilter = 0` and make 2 different queries

Comment: @ughai In this case I cant do that either.

Comment: the part `or @UseFilter = 0` should be meaningless when @UserFilter is set as 1. what is the execution plan when the @UserFilter is set to 0?

Perhaps try `WHERE pkEventID CASE WHEN @UseFilter = 0 THEN 57637 ELSE IS NOT NULL END` (guessing from the name it's not nullable

Comment: @ZoharPeled When `@UseFilter = 0` all rows are returned and the execution plan is the same as the one not using the index (Index scan, nonClustered)

Comment: Is an index hint an option for you?
For dynamic search conditions have a look here: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: If `EventEvent` is a table with PK; it should be clustered, As same as mine that I try it with `or @var`, Please add a `CREATE` script of `EventEvent` ;).

Comment: @shA.t Yes the pk is using a clustered index as can be seen in image two.

Answer (score 1):

Optimizing `or` is hard, as your example shows.  One way around this is to use dynamic SQL.  You can also try this:

```
DECLARE @UseFilter as bit = 1

select pkEventId
from EventEvent
where pkEventID = 57637
UNION ALL
select pkEventId
from EventEvent
where pkEventID <> 57637 AND @UseFilter = 0;
```

It is possible that the second subquery will short-circuit because of the comparison of the constant.

EDIT:

This version may do what you really want:

```
select pkEventId
from EventEvent
where pkEventID = 57637 AND  @UseFilter = 1
UNION ALL
select pkEventId
from EventEvent
where @UseFilter = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems the query after the union is not using the index.

Comment: `pkEventID <> 57637 AND` is wrong, it should select ALL rows if if `@UseFilter = 0`

Comment: @Aツ . . . This is a `union all` query.  Those are retrieved by the first subquery.  Magnus, does the second part slow down the query?  The question is whether the engine will short-circuit the table scan because of the constant condition.

Comment: why would the first part return a single row if `@UseFilter = 0`?

Comment: It seems to be the same problem with the updated query. It does an Index scan.

Comment: @Magnus . . . Here is a related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435420/does-sql-server-optimise-constant-expressions).  I'm pretty sure that SQL Server will remove constant expressions.  However, is it possible that the query is getting compiled and then run with different parameters?  If so, you might need to recompile the query each time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see my Index scan is `Clustered` !

Here is my `Table_1` Create Script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [col1] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [col1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Yes but it is doing a scan not a seek.